# Pyspark SQL: How to left join dataframe A and dataframe B on two columns where dataframe B columns are NULL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a script for a daily incremental load process using Pyspark and a Hive table which has already been initially loaded with data.

I've been trying to create a `UC dataframe` by left outer joining an `INC dataframe` and `BASE dataframe` on two PK columns `src_sys_id` & `acct_nbr` where `INC dataframe` columns are NULL.

I've tried the following syntax:

```
uc_df = base_df.join(base_df, inc_df("src_sys_id") == base_df("src_sys_id") &
inc_df("fleet_acct_nbr") == base_df("fleet_acct_nbr"),"left_outer").filter(inc_df("*").isNull).show(false)
```

But I keep getting syntax errors whenever I attempt to run the code block above...stating that a `dataframe object is not callable`

I don't have much experience running sql functions or queries w/Pyspark, so any suggestions or help is appreciated guys.

Comment: You are clearly not ready to use pyspark. Are you familiar with SQL?

Comment: & You clearly have your panties in a bunch for whatever reason snowflake. Either answer the question, offer some useful advice, or keep scrolling.

But so you know.. I’m working on a ETL script with pre-existing code for which TempViews & TempTables cant be used because of the nature of the data set and the code before this block which can’t be shown.

Comment: You killed me with that "snowflake":-)) obviously my comment didn't land right... sorry for that. There where so many syntax errors in the provided code, therefore I was trying to guide you in another direction that might have suit you better. Also provided you with a detailed answer. Good luck with that ETL!

Answer (score 0):

**Sample dataset**

```
base_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,10,100),(2,20,200),(3,30,300),(4,40,400),(5,50,500)], 'id int, src_sys_id int, fleet_acct_nbr int')
inc_df  = spark.createDataFrame([(1,20,200),(2,40,400)], 'id int, src_sys_id int, fleet_acct_nbr int')
```

**1st option (PySpark)**

```
uc_df = base_df.join(inc_df, ['src_sys_id','fleet_acct_nbr'], "leftanti")
```

**2nd option (Spark SQL)**

```
base_df.createOrReplaceTempView('base')
inc_df.createOrReplaceTempView('inc')

sql_stmt = '''
select * 
from   base left anti join inc using (src_sys_id, fleet_acct_nbr)
'''

uc_df = spark.sql(sql_stmt)
```

**Results**

```
uc_df.show()

+----------+--------------+---+
|src_sys_id|fleet_acct_nbr| id|
+----------+--------------+---+
|        10|           100|  1|
|        30|           300|  3|
|        50|           500|  5|
+----------+--------------+---+
```

---

**As for your attempted solution:**

- You cannot use dataframe like this: `df(...)`. It is not a function, therefore it is not callable. That is the reason for the error you get. You can reference a column by using `df.col` or `df['col']`
- `&` has precedence over `=`. You should surround your equality conditions with brackets.
- `inc_df['*'].isNull()` Is not a valid use for `*`. You should use a column.
- Assigning `show(...)` to a dataframe will give you None.
- `.show(false)` is wrong for 2 reasons: (1) The first parameter should be integer. (2) false literal in Python is uppercased: `False`. You should read the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show.html?highlight=show#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show).

**Here are a couple of options to fix your original code**

```
uc_df = (base_df
         .join(inc_df, 
               (inc_df.src_sys_id == base_df.src_sys_id) & (inc_df.fleet_acct_nbr == base_df.fleet_acct_nbr),
               "left_outer")
         .filter(inc_df.src_sys_id.isNull())
        )
```

---

```
uc_df = (base_df
         .join(inc_df,
               (inc_df['src_sys_id'] == base_df['src_sys_id']) & (inc_df['fleet_acct_nbr'] == base_df['fleet_acct_nbr']),
               "left_outer")
         .filter(inc_df['src_sys_id'].isNull())
        )
```

**and a similar solution in Spark SQL**

```
base_df.createOrReplaceTempView('base')
inc_df.createOrReplaceTempView('inc')

sql_stmt = '''
select  * 

from                base as b 

        left join  inc   as i 
        
        on         b.src_sys_id     = i.src_sys_id
              and  b.fleet_acct_nbr = i.fleet_acct_nbr
              
where   i.src_sys_id is null
'''

uc_df = spark.sql(sql_stmt)
```